# autodoc: workaround when "cannot import module"

Tags: python, python-sphinx, pybind11, read-the-docs, autodoc

The package I want to document with Sphinx contains pure Python modules (ok) + a C/C++ library bind using pybind11.
There are a lot of dependencies that can not reasonnably be built on ReadTheDocs!

So on RTD, `autodoc` can not import my library to extract the docstrings...

My first idea was to generate `_build/doctrees` locally and use it on RTD. But it contains binary files, heavy to store in the repository: no.

Is there a way to "expand" autodoc directives in RST files? It could produce full text of RST files or a fake static module as a `.py`...

Thanks in advance for your ideas!

Mathieu

Comment: Perhaps you can use this: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_mock_imports

Comment: No because using pybind the docstrings are in the `lib.so`. If I "mock" it, I have no docstrings :D

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but there are other projects on Read the Docs that depend on pybind11. See https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/9034

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two potential ways to grab the docstrings from C/C++ compiled libraries:

#### Option 1

Install all the system dependencies to install/build the Python packages you need. This can be achieved on Read the Docs by using the key `build.apt_packages` in the config file (see https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html)

#### Option 2

Try using `sphhinx-autoapi` extension (https://sphinx-autoapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead `autodoc`. This extension does not require to have the dependencies installed since it works statically by parsing the files directly instead of inspecting them dynamically.

Comment: Yes, another solution would be to extend `sphinx-autoapi` to parse `pybind11` code.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small tool that produces Python code from a compiled Python extension (signatures and docstrings of course).

In the case, it can be useful for others:
https://gitlab.com/doc-tools/pydoc-codedoc

(still incomplete of course)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: sorry, I checked the group visibility but not the project!